# Progress Bar will not complete

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a worker, and a progress bar. progress bar is in the View and the worker is in the model.
I want to show progress bar to the user so they know how long they have to wait. for all results to finish populating.

Worker thread looks like this

Model

```
ManagementObjectSearcher MetaClasses = new ManagementObjectSearcher(CurrentScope, new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM meta_class"));
int index = 0;
int Total = MetaClasses.Get().Count;
foreach (ManagementObject Metaclass in MetaClasses.Get())
{
    try
    {
        index++;
        BGW.ReportProgress((index * 100) / Total, Metaclass["__CLASS"].ToString());
    }
    catch { }
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

the worker sends the information to the ProgressUpdated method, i did this so the UI updated with the availible data for the end user.

Model

```
public void Workers_Changed(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Progress = e.ProgressPercentage;
    switch (TaskToRun)
    {
        case "NameSpace":
            {
                BaseClasses.Add(e.UserState.ToString());
                if (Progress == 100) { Thread.Sleep(200); }
                break;
            }
        case "Class":
            {
                return;
            }
    }
}
```

Again Works perfectly.
My progress bar Value is bound as well.

XAML

```
<ProgressBar Height="20" Name="ProgressBar_WMI"
             Value="{Binding Progress,Mode=OneWay}"
             DockPanel.Dock="Top"
             Minimum="1"
             Maximum="100" Foreground="Red"  ValueChanged="ProgressBar_WMI_ValueChanged" />
```

**Issue:** when the progressbar hits about 95% it doesn't show as completed in the UI thread

View (Xaml.CS)

```
public void HideProgressBar()
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    ProgressBar_WMI.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

public void ProgressBar_WMI_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ProgressBar_WMI.Value == ProgressBar_WMI.Maximum)
    {
        ProgressBar_WMI.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
        HideProgressBar();
    }
    else {
        ProgressBar_WMI.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
        ProgressBar_WMI.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

My idea is to have the bar hit to 100% completed and turn green to indicate that its completed and the disappear/collapse after 3 seconds.

Any Idea's?

Comment: Call HideProgressBar asynchronously using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. This will give the window chance to redraw itself, so that `Thread.Sleep(3000)` is executed when progress bar is drawn in the filal state. `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => HideProgressBar()));`

Comment: Im assuming that your talking about using the Dispatcher in the public void ProgressBar_WMI_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) Method, i have updated the code and still i am encountering issues.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible reasons for your `ProgressBar` not reaching 100%. The first is simply because you might be hiding it as soon as it reaches that point and so, you never *actually* see it.

The other *possible* reason is that this calculation *never* reaches your maximum limit value:

```
BGW.ReportProgress((index * 100) / Total, Metaclass["__CLASS"].ToString());
```

Only you can verify that, but you *might* be losing some precision in the actual calculation by using `int`s here... I *am* aware that the `ReportProgress` method takes an `int`

Comment: if (ProgressBar_WMI.Value == ProgressBar_WMI.Maximum), inidicates not to perform said action untill the Maximum is reached. using break points shows that the value = the maximum.